# Superannuation drawdown for non-resident

Tags: retirement, australia, superannuation

I'm an Australia citizen but not a resident. I worked there for ~10 years and have a considerable amount of money in my (compulsory) superannuation account. It's consolidated and relatively low fee, but it's really just dormant money.

I now live and work overseas. Is there any way I can get that money *out* of the superannuation fund and combine it with my other savings? It's far from ideal for me to have this money locked up in a foreign country, in a foreign denomination.

If not, what are my options?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/Super/In-detail/Withdrawing-and-paying-tax/Withdrawing-your-super-and-paying-tax/) are your options.

While you remain an Australian citizen you cannot withdraw super just because you are residing overseas. You could renounce your citizenship - just make sure you have another one to fall back on.

Comment: Yes, I withdrew my super pre-1999 before the rules changed. Now it's hard to access outside retirement.

Comment: please quote important information from the link, otherwise if the link rots the answer become worthless.

Comment: link rot has occurred. Link gives 404 error.